# Common OpenGL cleanup operation WITHOUT destroying context

Tags: c++, opengl

Recently, I've been doing offscreen GPU acceleration for my **real-time** program.

I want to create a context and reuse it several times (100+). And I'm using `OpenGL 2.1 and GLSL version 1.20`.

Each time I reuse the context, I'm going to do the following things:

- Compile `shaders`, link `program` then `glUsePrograme` (Question 1: should I relink the `program` or re-create the `program` each time?)
- Generate `FBO` and `Texture`, then bind them so I can do offscreen rendering. (Question2: should I destroy those `FBO` and `Texture`)
- Generate `GL_Array_BUFFER` and put some vertices data in it. (Question3: Do I even need to clean this?)
- glDrawArray bluh bluh...
- Call `glFinish()` then copy data from GPU to CPU by calling `glReadPixels`.

And is there any other necessary cleanup operation that I should consider?

Answer (score 0):

If you can somehow cache or otherwise keep the OpenGL object IDs, then you should not delete them and instead just reuse them on the next run. Unless you acquire new IDs reusing the old ones will either replace the existing objects (properly releasing their allocations) or just change their data.

The call to `glFinish` before `glReadPixels` is superfluous, because `glReadPixels` causes an implicit synchronization and finish.